# R write.table read.table change the format of some columns in dataframes

Tags: r, class, shiny, read.table, write.table

I am experienced a problem when saving data using `write.table` and reading data using `read.table`.

I wrote some code that collect data from thousands of files, does some calculations, and creates a data frame. In this data frame I have 8 columns and more then 11000 rows. The columns contain the 8 variables, 3 of which are ordered factors; the other variables are numeric.

When I look at the structure of my data before using the command `write.table` I got exactly what I expect which is:

```
str(data)
'data.frame':   11424 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ a_KN      : num  8.56e-09 1.11e-08 1.45e-08 1.88e-08 2.45e-08 ...
 $ a_DTM     : num  5.05e-08 5.12e-08 5.19e-08 5.26e-08 5.33e-08 ...
 $ SF        : num  5.89 4.6 3.58 2.79 2.18 ...
 $ Energy    : Ord.factor w/ 6 levels "160"<"800"<"1.4"<..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ EnergyUnit: Ord.factor w/ 3 levels "MeV"<"GeV"<"TeV": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Location  : Ord.factor w/ 7 levels "BeamImpact"<"WithinBulky"<..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ Ti        : num  0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 1 0.25 1 0.25 ...
 $ Tc        : num  30 28 26 24 22 20 30 18 28 16 ...
```

After that I use the usual `write.table` command to save my file:

```
write.table(data, file = "filename.txt")
```

Now, when I read again this file into R, and I look at the structure, I get this:

```
mydata <- read.table("filename.txt", header=TRUE)

> str(mydata)
'data.frame':   11424 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ a_KN      : num  8.56e-09 1.11e-08 1.45e-08 1.88e-08 2.45e-08 ...
 $ a_DTM     : num  5.05e-08 5.12e-08 5.19e-08 5.26e-08 5.33e-08 ...
 $ SF        : num  5.89 4.6 3.58 2.79 2.18 ...
 $ Energy    : num  160 160 160 160 160 160 160 160 160 160 ...
 $ EnergyUnit: Factor w/ 3 levels "GeV","MeV","TeV": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Location  : Factor w/ 7 levels "10cmTarget","AdjBulky",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ Ti        : num  0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 1 0.25 1 0.25 ...
 $ Tc        : int  30 28 26 24 22 20 30 18 28 16 ...
```

Do you know how to solve this problem? THis bothers me also because I am creating a Shiny app and this changed class doesn't fit my purpose.

Thanks!

Comment: See `?read.table` and the `colClasses` argument - you can set the classes manually when reading a CSV (at least to factors, not ordered factors).

Comment: take in mind that the text file doesn't understand `factor` variables that is proper of R. But, for example, if you save it like `.rds` file the structer is mantained (`saveRDS, readRDS`)

Comment: Thanks for your comments @lukeA, @Andriy T.  But now I have a new error: `Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  scan() expected 'a real', got '"1"'`

Comment: Ok. Problem solved. My mistake . Thanks again!